# How do I find the expression for where the first derivative equals 0?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a simple function of time.  If I take the first derivative and set it equal to 0.0 I get the extrema of that function.  I'm not interested in a numerical result, I want an expresion involving time and the rest of the parameters in my equations.

`Solve[]` gives `Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.`

How do I get an expression by setting the first derivative equal to 0.0?  My code is below.  (I've solved this on paper.  I want  Mathematica to give some plots and typeset the equations.)

Related question:  The step that computes the derivative gives a result that includes this expression: `Sqr'[-p1x + p2x - t v1x + t v2x]`.  What is `Sqr'`, the `Sqr` function followed by an apostrophe?

Thanks.

```
p1tx = p1x + v1x*t
p1ty = p1y + v1y*t
p1t = p1xt + p1yt

p2tx = p2x + v2x*t
p2ty = p2y + v2y*t
p2t = p2xt + p2yt

dt = Sqrt[Sqr[p2tx - p1tx] + Sqr[p2ty - p1ty]]

firstDeriv = D[dt,t]
Solve[firstDeriv==0,t]
```

Comment: Sorry for the cross post.  After posting here I noticed the low traffic on SO and so cross posted to Mathematica SE.  I'm new to Mathematica and the Mathematica community.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it has been asked and answered elsewhere -- http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61879/how-do-i-find-the-expression-for-where-the-first-derivative-equals-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is Sqr', the Sqr function followed by an apostrophe

I think it is just a typo `dt = Sqrt[Sqrt[p2tx - p1tx] + Sqrt[p2ty - p1ty]]`

```
{{t -> (-p1y v1x^2 + p2y v1x^2 + p1x v1y^2 - p2x v1y^2 + 
      2 p1y v1x v2x - 2 p2y v1x v2x - p1y v2x^2 + p2y v2x^2 - 
      2 p1x v1y v2y + 2 p2x v1y v2y + p1x v2y^2 - 
      p2x v2y^2)/((v1y - v2y) (v1x^2 - v1x v1y - 2 v1x v2x + v1y v2x +
         v2x^2 + v1x v2y - v2x v2y))}}
```

ps: `I've solved this on paper` So, how does your equation for derivative look like?

Comment: The error was that there is no Sqr function in Mathematica.  When I used ^2 Solve[] gave the correct result.  Apparently the `Sqr'` in the result was Mathematica telling me I used an invalid function call.

Comment: @DeanSchulze no, if it does not know the function it leaves as in notation as some function and `'` means derivative of it which it can not simplify as it does not know what this function is.